# Google Cloud VMs has dissapeared

Tags: virtual-machines, google-compute-engine, cloud, google

This is my problem. I had payed for 3 VMs on google cloud for 2 years. My service has ended 3 months ago and I couldt renovate that services for budget problems. Nowadays I have the budget and I need to continue with my VMs but they just have dissapeared, my VMs console does show nothing . I don't know if I lost all my work and information. what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have [disabled billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#disable_billing_for_a_project) on the your GCP project. If that's the scenario, resources like GCE VM might had removed from that project after a certain period of time.

At this point, I would highly recommend you to contact the '[billing and payment support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/)' team to get further assistance.

Since you have stopped paying before 3 months ago, the possibility of the [removal](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues#resolving_declined_payments) of a Google Compute Engine resource(Ex: GCE VM) from that unpaid project account is high.

Answer (score 0):

Once the service has ended, the [resources might be removed](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7006543?hl=en). Mainly because, even if the VMs have been stopped, there are still the persistent disks which are incurring charges. These resources cannot be recovered.

Comment: Hi, please edit if it apply, as your link is talking about the data retention in trial, where the OP was in a paid subscription, before stopping paying.

Comment: It's the same thing. Once your free trial is completed, so does the billing. The main root cause of this issue is that there is nowhere to bill the resources which is why eventually they were removed